# Como acessar o conteudo desse subArray?

Tags: javascript, array

Eu consigo acessar o conteúdo de um Array assim:

```
{{teste02[0]}}
```

E obtenho como retorno o seguinte:

```
{"assigned_date":"1969-12-31 21:00:00.000","user_id":"101","role_id":"101","group_id":
{"path":"/administrador","displayName":"Administrador","icon":"",
"name":"administrador","description":"","parent_path":"",
"creation_date":"2017-08-18 11:04:28.846","id":"302",
"created_by_user_id":"-1","last_update_date":"2017-08-18 11:04:28.846"},"assigned_by_user_id":"-1"}
```

Porém o que eu realmente preciso é acessar o conteúdo do subArray `name`. Já tentei `{{teste02[0][0].name}}` mas nada me é retornado, como poderia acessar isso?

Comment: Descobri, na verdade o modo como deveria ter colocado era assim: `{{teste02[0].group_id.name}}`, não sei se nesse caso fecho a pergunta ou apenas respondo a mesmo com isso, se puderem me indicar o correto a fazer agradeço

Comment: Você pode responder o que fez para resolver e se tiver referencias sobre o assunto postar na sua resposta.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no modo como tentei acessar o conteúdo do subArray, eu havia errado o caminho completo que precisava disponibilizar para acessar seu conteúdo.

Inicialmente eu havia colocado assim: `{{teste02[0].name}}`
Porém antes de conseguir acessar esse conteúdo havia o subArray `group_id`. No fim o correto era colocar assim : `{{teste02[0].group_id.name}}`